# List and change client activities assignee and dates

Tags: profile, activities

I want to create a profile[?] where I:

select a client then

list all the activities for a client, sorted by date,

where I can assign/change the staff member assigned to the activity and

change the date.

Is there a sample? I looked at the following but it's not quite basic enough for me. If I had a sample of such a profile I might be able to adjust it to work for me.

[Including Activity Dates and Subjects in a Profile for a Directory or Search](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/including-activity-dates-and-subjects-in-a-profile-for-a-directory-or-search)

Comment: What CMS and version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.6.6 on Drupal 7.37. Thanks